# MVC .NET using Html.EditorFor in my controller

Tags: model-view-controller, templates, code-behind

I'm using Custom Editor Templates in my view, and I would to know if is possible to obtain the same result from my controller.

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Book) %>
```

Does anyone knows if it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a possible solution:

add an user control and call Html.EditorFor(model => model.Book) inside.
Then in my controller I just have to call View(usercontrol,model)

Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: this one maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971028/how-can-i-call-editorfor-from-the-controller