# How can I call EditorFor from the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have list of locations

```
public class Location
{
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

I created editor template for this class

```
<div>
   <span>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.LocationName)</span>
   <span style="color: red;">@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Address )</span>
</div>
```

The problem is that locations load with ajax to my page and then I am going to send the results back to the server.
But how to get this location with specific index? I mean that for the first location it will generate like this:

```
<input type="text" name="Locations[0].LocationName" />
```

For the second location when I press "Add Location" button it should get this location from the server (from action of controller as html string) but with index 1 not 0 because it is next location.

Is it possible to achieve it? Or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: I would change this approach to a REST service endpoint for locations and save/load locations using this service.

Comment: i.e. create `LocationCotroller: ApiController` and implement `Get()`, `Get(id)`, `Put(id)`, `Post(id)` into it. User jquery to receive/send json to the service.

Comment: But I don't use REST service I have only contollers and action GetLocation(int index) and according this index I want to return the control.

Comment: >i.e. create LocationCotroller: ApiController
This is good approach but I want to user classic mvc with simple html form, so when I save locations it will send to the server all locations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this

```
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult LocationEditor(int index)
    {
        ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = string.Format("Locations[{0}]", index);
        return PartialView(@"EditorTemplateExplicitPathAsOnlyViewNameAintGonnaWork.cshtml");
    }
```

And for location names container

```
<div class="locations-container" data-item-count="@Model.Count">
    @for (int j = 0; j < Model.Count; j++)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model[j])
    }
    <a href="#" class="add-location">Add Location</a>
</div>
```

The rest of tiny bit of javascript to increment data-item-count upon adding and call `LocationNameEditorLocationNameEditor` action with new index is upon you.

Comment: This is really super solution!!! You are superstar with this solution! Thank you a lot buddy! I will use this solution. I forgot that we can changed HtmlFieldPrefix property directly! Thank you again!!!

Answer (score 2):

You could try using partial views and create an action method that returns an `AjaxResult` (I believe that's correct). Then you could have the controller populate the view model and pass it to the partial view that's to be rendered in your page at the place you specify.

Comment: That is right, I just dont like mess around and receive html chunks from ajax request when i can have plain data.

Comment: It's either that or re-render the entire page by calling your main action or do as others propose and create yourself a REST service.